# What does the routing table entry 129.0&0x8500 mean?

Tags: networking, routing, netstat

While attempting to diagnose some network problems, I looked at the routing table on my computer (Mac OS 10.9):

```
healslime> netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.7.120.1         UGSc           39        0     en0
default            10.6.168.1         UGScI           1        0     en1
10.6.168/21        link#6             UCS             2        0     en1
[some other ordinary entries omitted]
129.0&0x8500       ff.ff.ff.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.ff.ff.ff.85.0.0.40.7c.0.5.14.4.0.ad.de.7.8.0.0.3.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.f7.1.0.0.ef.be.ad.de.0.0.0.0.dc.5.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.f7.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.10.2.0.0.83.6b.41.e.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.10.2.0.0.a.7.78.1.4.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.7c.0.5.14.4.0.ad.de.7.8.0.0.3.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ef.be.ad.de.0.0.0.0.dc.5.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.10.2.0.0.83.6b.41.f.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.10.2.0 USc             0        9     en0
```

Question 1: What does the destination address `129.0&0x8500` mean?

Question 2: What in the name of Vinton G. Cerf is that gateway address?

Comment: That is indeed strange. All I can say is that this weird grammar (129.0&0x8500) is not understood by apps like ping, ssh, http (I tested it). So, unless the kernel has a different, unique way of writing IP addresses in this cryptic way, we are dealing with the product of an error. Two questions: does this route survive reboots? Were you recently on IPv6?

Comment: It's recurred many times over restarts, but I just restarted now and it disappeared. I'm monitoring the routing table at regular intervals and will see if I can figure out when it reappears.